# How to update record in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to update record in spring boot application but its adding a new record instead of updating and i also want to search

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity

public class Events {
    
private Long id;

private String game;

private String catergory;

private String venue;

private float entrance_fee;

private String date;

private String time;

private Timestamp created_time;


private String image;

public Events() {

    super();

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

public Long getId() {

    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {

    this.id = id;
}

public String getGame() {

    return game;
}

public void setGame(String game) {

    this.game = game;
}


public String getCatergory() {

    return catergory;
}

public void setCatergory(String catergory) {

    this.catergory = catergory;
}

public String getVenue() {

    return venue;
}

public void setVenue(String venue) {

    this.venue = venue;
}

public float getEntrance_fee() {

    return entrance_fee;
}

public void setEntrance_fee(float entrance_fee) {

    this.entrance_fee = entrance_fee;
}

public String getDate() {

    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {

    this.date = date;
}

public String getTime() {

    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {

    this.time = time;
}

public Timestamp getCreated_time() {

    return created_time;
}

public void setCreated_time(Timestamp created_time) {

    this.created_time = created_time;
}

public String getImage() {

    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {

    this.image = image;
}


@Transient

public String getImagePath() {

    if(image == null || id == null) return null;
    
    return "/event-images/" + id + "/" + image;
}

}
```

this is my repository...

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository

    public interface EventsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Events, Long> {
    
        List<Events> findByCatergoryLike(String catergory);
        
        
    
    }
```

this is my service..

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service

public class EventsService {

@Autowired

private EventsRepository eventsRepository;

public Page<Events> listAll(int pageNumber){

    Sort sort = Sort.by("date").ascending();

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber -1, 1, sort);

    return eventsRepository.findAll(pageable);  
}


public Events save(Events events) {

     return eventsRepository.save(events);
}

public void update(Events events) {

     eventsRepository.save(events);
}

public Events get(Long id) {

    return eventsRepository.findById(id).get();
}


public void delete(Long id) {

    eventsRepository.deleteById(id);
}

public List<Events> findBycatergory(String catergory) {
    
    return eventsRepository.findByCatergoryLike("%"+catergory+"%");
}



}
```

this is the update method in the controller..

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/update_event" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String upadate(@ModelAttribute("events") @PathVariable(name="id") Long id, Events events,

        @RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {

    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

    events.setImage(fileName);

    eventsService.update(events);

    String uploadDir = "./event-images/" + events.getId();

    Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);

    if(!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {

        Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
    }
    
    try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()){


    Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);

    Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);



    }catch (IOException e) {

        throw new IOException("Could not save uploaded file: " + fileName);
    }



    if(fileName.length()>1048576) {

        System.out.println("file too large");
    }
    return "redirect:/events";
    
}
```

then finally the update form..

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/update_event}" th:object="${Edit_events}" method="post" 

enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
            <div id="name">


            <h2 class="name">Sports</h2>

                <input class="firstname" type="text" th:field="*{game}" /><br>
                                
                 <input class="lastname" type="text" th:field="*{catergory}" /><br>
                
                </div>

            <h2 class="name">Venue</h2>

            <input  class="username" type="text" th:field="*{venue}" />
            
            <h2 class="name">Entrance Fee</h2>

            <input class="email" type="text" th:field="*{entrance_fee}" />
            
            <h2 class="name">Date & Time</h2>


            <input type="date" class="password" th:field="*{date}" />
           
            
             <input  type="time" class="number" th:field="*{time}" /><br>
           

                
             <img th:src="*{imagePath}">



             <input type="file" class="photoBtn" name="fileImage" id="fileImage" accept="image/png, 



image/jpeg"/> <button type="submit">SAVE CHANGES</button><a th:href="@{/events}">..DISCARD..</a>


           
        </form>
```

Comment: For updating the record you have to get the data from DB and update it and use save() method to insert the updated data in DB

Comment: Please take the time to `format` your code (and consider reducing the code to what's relevant to answer your question).

Answer (score 0):

the solution is pretty simple, you need to fetch the record first and then update it using save(events)
For ex: In request payload you get object of Event class, Use  `eventsRepository.findById(events.id)` JPA repository call to fetch the data and then update the returned instance and then save it, interanlly JPA checks the entry is already registered or not. if yes then it will update else it will create a new entry.

```
` Optinal<Events>currentEvent = eventsRepository.findById(events.id); if(currentEvent.isPresent()){// map the input values with currentEventusing mapper  eventsRepository.save(events) }`
```

Hope this is helpful

Comment: thank you sir but now its saying: Missing URI template variable 'id' for method parameter of type Long

Comment: If you want @ PathVariable, you need to specify placeholders in the @ RequestMapping entry to tell Spring where the path variables fit in the URI, For Ex: /update_event/{id}